# Can I have a drop down menu for multiple tabs, in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

Is there an extension in Chrome that letsm e have a drop down menu for multiple tabs.

As it becomes difficult when there are too many tabs like once it gets over 25-30 they start to blank out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Tabman Tabs Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabman-tabs-manager/hgmnkflcjcohihpdcniifjbafcdelhlm) and I like it.

[image: Image from Chrome Web Store]

Comment: very nice extension. I have switch my accepted answer to be your answer, because your extension has an option to dock it. That is a feature i've been looking for.  scroll bar is tiny though.

Answer (score 3):

There is an extension called Quicktabs, and an extension called Tab Menu.

Both are good.

Tab menu is a bit harder to find, but here it is mentioned  [on chromeplugins forum](http://www.chromeplugins.org/google/chrome-plugins/does-anybody-here-use-tab-menu-have-tab-menu-crx-file-41964.html#post91378)
which has a link to it [on mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/xp3ox7hx6tddy/Tab_Menu) and there's  [a link to it on ge.tt](http://ge.tt/1EmFikq/v/0)

Here is quicktabs on chrome extensions site- [quicktabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb?hl=en) it has a search which is good.

you can of course install both.

And to install Tab Menu, since it isn't on the chrome extensions site, but we have the crx file(the actual installation file), so you can drag the CRX file into tools..extensions and install it that way.

Comment: Thanks for this, was looking around for it for ages, annoying that it was removed from the chrome webstore.

Comment: @Jonno_FTW yeah I think the dickish author went to work for firefox for a bit and removed it.